# PHP - DOMDocument - need to change/replace an existing HTML tag w/ a new one

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm trying to change all `<P>` tags in a document to `<DIV>`.  This is what I've come up with, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($htmlfile_data);

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName("p") as $pnode ) {
    $divnode->createElement("div");
    $divnode->nodeValue = $pnode->nodeValue;
    $pnode->appendChild($divnode);
    $pnode->parentNode->removeChild($pnode);
}
```

This is the result I want:

Before:

```
<p>Some text here</p>
```

After:

```
<div>Some text here</div>
```

Comment: This works http://stackoverflow.com/a/21885789/175071

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are appending the `div` to your `p` which results in `<p><div></div></p>`, removing the `p` will remove everything.
Additionally `$divnode->createElement()` won't work when `$divnode` isn't initialized.

Try instead to use the [DOMDocument::replaceChild()](http://at.php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php) (the `div`s position in the dom will be the same as the `p`s).

```
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName("p") as $pnode ) {
    $divnode = $dom->createElement("div", $pnode->nodeValue);
    $dom->replaceChild($divnode, $pnode);
}
```

Comment: **One note:** if `$pnode->nodeValue` is not a plain text, but has extra nodes in it, only text will be left (html will be stripped).

Comment: You can't just replace items while iterating since the index changes and you end up with weird results.

Comment: guess what: I actually tested this at the time I answered it. So in case you use a recent PHP version foreach can handle the manipulation of the index.

Comment: as Sanne said their will be an error for multiple items. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018747/replace-tag-in-html-with-domdocument/12018817#12018817

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21885789/2209086)

```
function changeTagName( $node, $name ) {
    $childnodes = array();
    foreach ( $node->childNodes as $child ) {
        $childnodes[] = $child;
    }
    $newnode = $node->ownerDocument->createElement( $name );
    foreach ( $childnodes as $child ){
        $child2 = $node->ownerDocument->importNode( $child, true );
        $newnode->appendChild($child2);
    }
    if ( $node->hasAttributes() ) {
        foreach ( $node->attributes as $attr ) {
            $attrName = $attr->nodeName;
            $attrValue = $attr->nodeValue;
            $newnode->setAttribute($attrName, $attrValue);
        }
    }
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild( $newnode, $node );
    return $newnode;
}
```