# Remove links where href is disallowed

Tags: php, regex, dom

I have some links like this:

```
<a href="http://illegallink.com"><img src="something.jpg" /><a href="http://legallink.com">legal</a></a>
```

I want to remove all links that does **not** have "legallink.com" in it. But **still** keep the content. So the above input would output:

```
<img src="something.jpg" /><a href="http://legallink.com">legal</a>
```

It should work recursively through the links.

I found this regex that removes **all** links: `/<\\/?a(\\s+.*?>|>)/`, but I want it to keep links where href is legallink.com.

Can this be done with regex? Or should I use a DOM parser?

Comment: A DOM parser is needed, especially for nested <a> tags as in your example.

Comment: Can anyone give an example how I can achieve what I want? I have looked a lot, but can't find a solution.

Comment: Maybe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330545/php-html-dom-parser?

Comment: This related question might be useful: [How can I change the name of an element in DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/775904/367456)

Answer (score 1):

```
error_reporting(~0); display_errors(1);

$code = '<a href="http://illegallink.com"><img src="something.jpg" /><a href="http://legallink.com">legal</a></a>';

$document = new DOMDocument(); 
$document->loadHTML($code); 
$parser = new DOMXPath($document);  

foreach($parser->query("//a") as $node)  
{ 
  if (!preg_match("/^http:\/\/legallink.com/i", $node->getAttribute("href")))
  {
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($node->nodeValue, $node);
  }
}
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Comment: I'm not downvoter, but I believe he wants to find nested links, not links with a specific href. he was just using the href as an example to say which link should be kept.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - I should not be downvoted for unclear OP question. Besides of that nobody else posted alternative answers.

Comment: thats why I didn't downvote. the question needs some clarification.

Comment: @Elias: Please see the updated code, run it and tell us which error message you get.