# How to get the content of two xml tags even when they have another xml tags inside them (PHP-XML)

Tags: php, xml

In simple terms, let's suppose you have the following xml structure:

```
<TEXT>Well, I need some help as you <CUSTOMTAG>can</CUSTOMTAG> see.</TEXT>
```

When extracting the text of this node in PHP with strip_tags(), I am not getting the content of  tags.

**First step:**

What I want to do, is to extract and thus have the following string:

> "Well, I need some help as you can see."

**Second step:**

I would also like to convert the `<CUSTOMTAG>` and `</CUSTOMTAG>` to something else, like `<e>` and `</e>` for example, and finally have the following string:

```
"Well, I need some help as you <e>can</e> see."
```

I would appreciate only tested and working code.

Thanks in advance!

Kind Regards

Comment: **"I would appreciate only tested and working code."** Harry, on SO we appreciate you to try coding yourself and show what you've tried. This is not "order a code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part, you could use something like that:

```
<?php
$xml = "<TEXT>Well, I need some help as you <CUSTOMTAG>can</CUSTOMTAG> see, <CUSTOMTAG>maybe</CUSTOMTAG>.</TEXT>";

//1st part:
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xPath->query('//TEXT') as $textNode) {
  echo $textNode->textContent;
}
// 2nd part:
foreach ($xPath->query('//TEXT/CUSTOMTAG') as $find) {
  $find_value = $find->nodeValue;
  $replace = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
  $replace->appendXML('<e>'.$find_value.'</e>');
  $find->parentNode->insertBefore($replace, $find); 
  $parentnode = $find->parentNode;
  $parentnode->removeChild($find);
}
$result = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: You're welcome. The code is probably not the neatest, but it works (also for multiple instances of `<CUSTOMTAG>`)

Answer (score 0):

For the first step just use the following code:

```
<?php
$xml = "<TEXT>Well, I need some help as you <CUSTOMTAG>can</CUSTOMTAG> see.</TEXT>";

$domDoc  = new DOMDocument();
$domDoc->loadXML($xml);

$domXPath  = new DOMXPath($domDoc);
$textNodes = $domXPath->query('//TEXT');

foreach ($textNodes as $textNode) {
    echo $textNode->textContent;
}
```

For the second step just look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8164058/2000503.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :-) 
Is it possible though to achieve the same result by using SimpleXML?

Comment: Not that I know of, I use PHP SimpleXML most of the times I have to deal with XML, but in this case in particular I think DOMDocument is more suitable.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Both of you were remarkably helpful! Cheers!