# Automatically changing XML tags

Tags: php, xml, ftp

I'm wanting to automatically change tags within an XML file while keeping the original. I'm sure I could use php or perl to do this somehow, but for an example of what I'd like would be

file1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name>Name</name>
<surname>Surname</surname>
<telephone>0412345678</telephone>
```

then I'd like something to automatically change it once it hits my FTP server and save it as a new file, so file 2 would then be created

file2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<firstname>Name</firstname>
<lastname>Surname</lastname>
<mobile>0412345678</mobile>
```

Any push in the right direction is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/8164058/1301076

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is designed for this job. You just define a set of rules, something like

```
<xsl:template match="name">
  <firstname><xsl:value-of select="."/></firstname>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="surname">
  <lastname><xsl:value-of select="."/></lastname>
</xsl:template>
```

Arranging for the XSLT to be executed automatically when a file arrives at your FTP server is a different question: this is quite independent of what language you write the transformation in, and not something I can help you with.