# What is the best way to replace the punctuation in tag names?

Tags: php, regex, xml-parsing, preg-replace

I have my reasons to replace the punctuation character with a underscore in all tag names (please don't ask me why it is not relevant for the question).

What is relevant to the question is that I would like to:

```
<data:data>
    <another:data>Content</another:data>
    <another:data>Content</another:data>
    <another:data>Content</another:data>
    <another:data attribute="attr : content">This content should : not be affected</another:data>
    <another:data><![CDATA[This content should : not be affected]]></another:data>
</data:data>
```

Replace with:

```
<data_data>
    <another_data>Content</another_data>
    <another_data>Content</another_data>
    <another_data attribute="attr : content">This content should : not be affected</another_data>
    <another_data><![CDATA[This content should : not be affected]]></another_data>
</data_data>
```

But what is the best way to perform this with `php`?

I know that `regex` is not a proper way to parse `html` or `xml` but I'm afraid that I'm attached to use `preg_replace()` in my situation because `DOMDocument()` can't read my ~250K rows of bad structured namespaced provided xml- content. The provided xsd files (~25 schemes) are outdated (for 6 years now), the content- provider is unwilling to fix this.

I found out that `SimpleXMLElement()` works after replacing the `:` with `_`.

Comment: is it a single string or bunch of string?

Comment: It is a single string with around ~225K rows of content ;)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? :-)

Comment: I don't want to do this, but I have to this. The content is provided by someone who does not understand anything about namespaces and xsd files...

Comment: "Best way" usually depends on context. Is it template-HTML, or SGML, or real XML? A trivial regex would work for the latter.

Comment: The "best way" is based on the fact that regex is not a proper html- parser. It is xml.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Ok I think I've improved my question, it seems that there is more to take care about.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.sitepoint.com/simplexml-and-namespaces/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture what is between `<` and `>` then replace `:` with `_`, like this:

```
$string = "<data:data>
<another:data:data>Content:</another:data>
<another:data>:Content</another:data>
<another:data>Content</another:data>
<another:data><![CDATA[This content should : not be affected]]>Content</another:data>
</data:data>";

$regex = '~<[^!][^>]*>~';
$replaced = preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    function($m) { return str_replace(':', '_', $m[0]);},
    $string);

echo $replaced;
```

Output:

```
<data_data>                                                                                                                                                                                          
<another_data_data>Content:</another_data>                                                                                                                                                           
<another_data>:Content</another_data>                                                                                                                                                                
<another_data>Content</another_data>                                                                                                                                                                 
<another_data><![CDATA[This content should : not be affected]]>Content</another_data>                                                                                                                                                                   
</data_data>
```

Comment: I am very grateful to you and I think this is close by what I need, I'm still stuck with the content of the attributes and the content of CDATA between `<![` and `]>`. I've improved my question, can you look at it?

Comment: Changed satisfy between `<!` and `>`

Comment: Editted answer, please check

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use attributes, this code will work for you:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback(
    '#</?[\w:]+>#',
    function ($match) {
        list($tag) = $match;
        return str_replace(':', '_', $tag);
    },
    $string
);
```

If you do use attributes, check this out: [How do I change XML tag names with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163298/how-do-i-change-xml-tag-names-with-php)

Comment: Damn. I didnt mention that but there are attributes as well. Thanks for providing me this answer, I will look at the preg_replace_callback().

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the following:

```
$string = "<data:data>
<another:data>Content</another:data>
<another:data>Content</another:data>
<another:data>Content</another:data>
<another:data>Content</another:data>
</data:data>";

$string = str_replace(':', '_', $string);
```

or

```
$string = str_replace('another:data', 'another_data', $string);
```

***Update***

Maybe you can try the following:

```
$replace = array('another:data' => 'another_data', '/another:data' => '/another_data'); // So you can easily add more strings to replace
strtr($string, $replace);
```

link: http://php.net/strtr. I just found this so don't know if this is something for you.

Comment: This does effect the content as well.

Comment: Can you tell? how @Arek van Schaijk?

Comment: Well, all punctuation characters within the tags are replaced to.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh if in the content there is something with like `The last name of John is: herp` Then the `:` will be replaced with `_`

Comment: There are hundreds of different tags so your update does not affect this and I'm afraid I'm attached to use preg_replace().

Comment: why do you try to replace `/another:data`?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it was more to point out the functionality of the function than necessary. I know that it wouldn't change the outcome

Comment: @SuperDJ Dont know if this is the best option, because all the punctuation charachters within the tags also will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following regex,

```
<\/?\w+(:)\w+>
```

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vY7pC6/1)

You can use [Group](http://regexone.com/lesson/11) capture to replace it with `_`